# Elementos não estão bem responsivos e funcionais no bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, django, bootstrap-4

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/scrapy/style.css">

<div class="container w-50">
    <h1 class="display-4">Scrapy Data</h1>
    <!-- List group -->
    <div class="col-8 mx-auto my-5 py-5" id="Group">
        <div class="list-group">
                <div>
                    <a id="Tipos-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action mb-1 shadow-sm rounded-0" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTipos" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTipos">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <span>Tipos</span>
                            <div id="spinnerTipos" class="collapse spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-success ml-auto" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                        </div>                           
                            <a class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success collapse" id="collapseTipos" data-parent="#Group" role="button" href="/scrapy/scrapy-tipos" onclick="disableLinks(); showSpinners('#spinnerTipos');">Scrapy</a>

                    </a>
                </div>







                <div>
                    <a id="Habilidades-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action mb-1 shadow-sm rounded-0" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseHabilidades" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseHabilidades">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <span>Habilidades</span>
                            <div id="spinnerHabilidades" class="collapse spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-success ml-auto" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                        </div>


                            <a class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success collapse" id="collapseHabilidades" data-parent="#Group" role="button" href="/scrapy/scrapy-habilidades" onclick="disableLinks(); showSpinners('#spinnerHabilidades');">Scrapy</a>

                    </a>
                </div>







                <div>
                    <a id="Categorias-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action mb-1 shadow-sm rounded-0" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseCategorias" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseCategorias">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <span>Categorias</span>
                            <div id="spinnerCategorias" class="collapse spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-success ml-auto" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                        </div>


                            <a class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success collapse" id="collapseCategorias" data-parent="#Group" role="button" href="/scrapy/scrapy-categorias" onclick="disableLinks(); showSpinners('#spinnerCategorias');">Scrapy</a>

                    </a>
                </div>







                <div>
                    <a id="Pokemons-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action mb-1 shadow-sm rounded-0" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsePokemons" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsePokemons">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <span>Pokemons</span>
                            <div id="spinnerPokemons" class="collapse spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-success ml-auto" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                        </div>


                            <form class="form-inline collapse" action="index.html" method="post" id="collapsePokemons" data-parent="#Group">
                                <div class="ml-2 mt-2 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="idpoke" class="form-control" placeholder="Id do 1° pokémon ">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="ml-4 px-4 btn btn-outline-success" role="button" onclick="disableLinks(); showSpinners('#spinnerPokemons');">Scrapy</button>
                            </form>

                    </a>
                </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableLinks() {
        $("a").addClass("disabled");
    }
    function showSpinners(arg){
        $(arg).collapse()
        $("a").collapse('hide')
    }
</script>
```

Essa é uma parte do código. Estou usando esses spinners que aparecem sempre que aperto o botão scrapy, mas eles não estão responsivos quando uso em telas menores. Alguma dica?

Comment: Cara seria legal vc postar o código da forma que é renderizado no Browser, e não o código raw. Vai no Chrome aperta Ctrl+U e pega o HTML do componente e cola aqui, vai facilitar para te responder, de referência coloca o CSS que usou tb

Comment: pronto editei a pergunta e já tem o código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara basicamente o que acontece é que vc colocou seu `container` com a classe `w-50` e não usou um `Row` para separar seus grupos de conteúdo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu fiz foi remover a classe w-50 do `container` e separar o título e os `btns` em `rows` distintas. Agora ficou ok. Se vc quiser que os `btns` sejam mais estreitos basta trocar na div `<div class="col-8 mx-auto my-2 py-5" id="Group">` esse `col-8` por `col-6` por exemplo.

```js
function disableLinks() {
  $("a").addClass("disabled");
}

function showSpinners(arg) {
  $(arg).collapse()
  $("a").collapse('hide')
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 class="display-4 mx-auto">Scrapy Data</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- List group -->
      <div class="col-8 mx-auto my-2 py-5" id="Group">
        <div class="list-group">
          <div>
            <a id="Tipos-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action mb-1 shadow-sm rounded-0" data-toggle="collapse"
              href="#collapseTipos" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTipos">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span>Tipos</span>
                <div id="spinnerTipos" class="collapse spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-success ml-auto" role="status"
                  aria-hidden="true"></div>
              </div>
              <a class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success collapse" id="collapseTipos" data-parent="#Group" role="button"
                href="/scrapy/scrapy-tipos" onclick="disableLinks(); showSpinners('#spinnerTipos');">Scrapy</a>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div>
            <a id="Habilidades-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action mb-1 shadow-sm rounded-0"
              data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseHabilidades" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseHabilidades">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span>Habilidades</span>
                <div id="spinnerHabilidades" class="collapse spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-success ml-auto"
                  role="status" aria-hidden="true"></div>
              </div>
              <a class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success collapse" id="collapseHabilidades" data-parent="#Group" role="button"
                href="/scrapy/scrapy-habilidades" onclick="disableLinks(); showSpinners('#spinnerHabilidades');">Scrapy</a>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div>
            <a id="Categorias-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action mb-1 shadow-sm rounded-0" data-toggle="collapse"
              href="#collapseCategorias" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseCategorias">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span>Categorias</span>
                <div id="spinnerCategorias" class="collapse spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-success ml-auto" role="status"
                  aria-hidden="true"></div>
              </div>
              <a class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success collapse" id="collapseCategorias" data-parent="#Group" role="button"
                href="/scrapy/scrapy-categorias" onclick="disableLinks(); showSpinners('#spinnerCategorias');">Scrapy</a>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div>
            <a id="Pokemons-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action mb-1 shadow-sm rounded-0" data-toggle="collapse"
              href="#collapsePokemons" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsePokemons">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span>Pokemons</span>
                <div id="spinnerPokemons" class="collapse spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-success ml-auto" role="status"
                  aria-hidden="true"></div>
              </div>
              <form class="form-inline collapse" action="index.html" method="post" id="collapsePokemons" data-parent="#Group">
                <div class="ml-2 mt-2 form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="idpoke" class="form-control" placeholder="Id do 1° pokémon ">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="ml-4 px-4 btn btn-outline-success" role="button" onclick="disableLinks(); showSpinners('#spinnerPokemons');">Scrapy</button>
              </form>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda cara

Comment: @CAIOWANDERLEY sem problemas jovem, que bom que ajudou